# vim-airline tabs don't work. resetting airline theme when switching tabs

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline

I faced an issue[image]
As you can see on the screenshot, `vim` does not show tabs with specified `airline` theme and it shows me this annoying `X` button at the end of the tabline.
Here's my `.vimrc`:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

"Theme Section
colo minimalist
let g:airline_theme='minimalist'
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_close_button = 0
set nu
```

I've created another tab:
[image]
If I go back to the previous one, my `airline` theme resets to the default one:
[image]
And if I switch to the new tab, this default theme stays and annoys me.
**But**, here's some *magic*:[image]
If I open a directory using `vim`, `airline` themed tabline seems to be working.
[image]
When I switch tabs, `airline` tabline theme resets again:[image]
Help me, please.

Comment: This seems like a serious bug. What version of airline are you using? What version of vim? Is there other code (`~/.vim`) that could be interfering? Autocommands, etc.?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble no, my `.vimrc` contains only those several lines of code, nothing else. vim version is 8.2.0148-1, vim-airline 0.10-1, vim-airline-themes r1321.3bfe1d0-1.

Answer (score 0):

Setting everything up with `Vundle` (instead of `Pathogen`) fixed the bug. Now everything works!
[image]